# How do we find the antiderivative of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can we find the antiderivative of $x^x$? I  know that $\int x^xdx$ is not an elementary  expression, but can we find another expression？

Comment: Try with $\displaystyle \int_1^x t^tdt$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Somophore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Whet you can do is to write
$$x^x=e^{x\log(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n \log^n(x)}{n!}$$ and face integrals
$$I_n=\int x^n \log^n(x)\,dx$$ which write
$$I_n=\log ^{n+1}(x) (-E_{-n}(-(n+1) \log (x)))$$ where appear exponential integral functions.